# Preserving indention in generated output

Tags: xslt

I am having trouble getting my indention to line up correctly when generating some code with XSLT.

In the **Generated Code** you will notice that the first `public Builder name...` is aligned the intended way. But the rest of that method is not aligned correctly and then all the other methods are not aligned correctly. I intended for them to be indented to follow the indention of the rest of the code.

How do I fix this alignment issue?

**Don't worry about the correctness of the generated code, just trying to show an example.**

---

**The XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

    <xsl:output method="text" name="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="..." mode="builder">public Builder <xsl:value-of select="fu:lowercaseFirstLetter(@name)"/>(final String value) {
        this.dao.getMy<xsl:value-of select="fu:capitalizeFirstLetter(../@name)"/>().set<xsl:value-of select="fu:capitalizeFirstLetter(@name)"/>(value);
        return this;
    }
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match... >
        <xsl:result-document href="..." format="text">
public class <xsl:value-of select="..."/> implements Parent {

    public boolean test(Object o) {

        <xsl:apply-templates mode="builder"/>

        return true;

    }

}

        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**The Generated Code**

```
public class ATest implements Parent {

    public boolean test(Object o) {

        public Builder name(final String value) {
        dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
        return this;
    }
    public Builder name(final String value) {
        dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
        return this;
    }
    public Builder name(final String value) {
        dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
        return this;
    }
    public Builder name(final String value) {
        dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
        return this;
    }

        return true;

    }

}
```

---

**Intended Outcome**

```
public class ATest implements Parent {

    public boolean test(Object o) {

        public Builder name(final String value) {
            dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
            return this;
        }
        public Builder name(final String value) {
            dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
            return this;
        }
        public Builder name(final String value) {
            dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
            return this;
        }
        public Builder name(final String value) {
            dao.getMyATest().set_valid(value);
            return this;
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

Comment: what is indention? You meant Indentation?

Comment: No, i mean indention. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indention

Comment: okay... google pointed to Indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: don't worry about indentation of the generated Java, put it through a formatter as a post-processing phase.

Solution 2: take great care over the production of whitespace. Always use xsl:text to enclose any literal text output to the result, including whitespace, to distinguish whitespace you want to output from whitespace used to make the stylesheet readable. Have an "indent" parameter on all your template rules giving the current indentation level, and add X to it when calling apply-templates

```
<xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$indent + 2"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Have a function or named template to generate the indentation whitespace:

```
<xsl:call-template name="do-indent">
  <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$indent + 2"/>
</xsl:call-templates>
```

Comment: I was actually working on a very similar solution just now and it is working. I like the way yours looks better. Thanks!